# Formula for determinant of block matrix with commuting blocks

Tags: matrices, determinant, block-matrices

On [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Block_matrices), I saw the following formula

$$\det\begin{bmatrix}A & B\\ C & D\end{bmatrix} = \det(AD-BC)$$

if $C$ and $D$ commute. Is this always true?

Or is there a good counter example for each $2 \times 2$ block matrices?

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1296257/339790

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, it's always true, but note that there is a premise to fulfill: **$C$ and $D$ have to commute**, that is, we need $CD=DC$. If this condition is violated, the formula *may* fail to hold.

More generally, when the entries of $A,B,C,D$ be matices over a commutative ring (this includes, but isn't limited to, the cases where $A,B,C,D$ are real or complex matrices), we have
$$
\det \pmatrix{A&B\\ C&D}=
\begin{cases}
\det(AD-BC) & \text{ if } CD=DC,\\
\det(DA-CB) & \text{ if } AB=BA,\\
\det(DA-BC) & \text{ if } BD=DB,\\
\det(AD-CB) & \text{ if } AC=CA.
\end{cases}
$$
This was first proved by M. H. Ingraham (see his paper [*A note on determinants*](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.bams/1183499928)) and later proved independently by John Silvester (see [his paper](https://web.archive.org/web/20210923044734/http://www.ee.iisc.ac.in/new/people/faculty/prasantg/downloads/blocks.pdf)). Essentially, suppose $AC=CA$ (this is the last case in the above). Then
$$
\pmatrix{I&0\\ -C&A+xI}\pmatrix{A+xI&B\\ C&D}=\pmatrix{A+xI&B\\ AC-CA&(A+xI)D-CB}.
$$
By assumption, $AC-CA=0$, so the RHS is block-triangular and
$$\det(A+xI)\,\det\pmatrix{A+xI&B\\ C&D}=\det(A+xI)\,\det\left((A+xI)D-CB\right).$$
As $\det(A+xI)$ is a nonzero polynomial in $x$, we can divide both sides by it and obtain $\det\pmatrix{A+xI&B\\ C&D}=\det\left((A+xI)D-CB\right)$. Put $x=0$, the assertion follows. The proofs for the other three cases are similar.

**Remark.** Those who are familiar with [Schur complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement) may recognise that the same technique using block matrix decomposition is also used in the derivation of Schur complement. In fact, if the matrix entries are taken from a field, we can use Schur complement to prove the above formula. E.g. suppose again that $AC=CA$. Let $x$ be  an indeterminate and extend the underlying field $F$ to $F(x)$, the field containing all rational functions in $x$. Then $A+xI$ is invertible and it commutes with $C$. Therefore, by using Schur complement, we get
\begin{aligned}
\det\pmatrix{A+xI&B\\ C&D}
&=\det(A+xI)\det\left(D-C(A+xI)^{-1}B\right)\\
&=\det(A+xI)\det\left(D-(A+xI)^{-1}CB\right)\\
&=\det\left((A+xI)D-CB\right)
\end{aligned}
and the assertion again follows by putting $x=0$.

Comment: +1. It would good to elucidate why the equality for multitude of $x\ne0$ justifies the equality for $x=0$.