# Eigenvalues of Augmented Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be an invertible real $n\times n$ matrix and suppose the singular values of $A$ are in the interval $[1,\kappa_2(A)]$, where $\kappa_2(A)$ denotes the (2-norm) condition number of $A$. Consider
$$M=\left[\begin{array}{cc}I & A\\ A^T & 0\end{array}\right].$$
Results from various papers I've found claim that the eigenvalues of such augmented systems in general (where $I$ is replaced by an arbitrary square matrix) are contained within a union of one negative interval and one positive interval $[a,b]\cup[c,d]$, i.e., $a,b<0$ and $c,d>0$. These two intervals moreover can be written directly in terms of the condition number of $A$. How can I show that this is true? Applying a factorization trick, we can deduce that
$$
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
I & A \\
A^T & 0
\end{array}
\right]
=
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
I & 0 \\
A^T & I
\end{array}
\right]
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
I & 0 \\
0 & -A^TA
\end{array}
\right]
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
I & A \\
0 & I
\end{array}
\right]
.$$
Does this help us see the range of the eigenvalues?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $A=USV^T$ is a singular value decomposition. Using the [block matrix determinant formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/548487/1551), we get
$$
\det(xI-M) = \det\left((x-1)xI-AA^T\right) = \det\left((x-1)xI-S^2\right).
$$
Therefore the eigenvalues of $M$ are the roots of $x^2 - x - \sigma_i^2$, i.e. pairs of numbers of the form $\frac{1 \pm \sqrt{1+4\sigma_i^2}}2$, where $\sigma_1,\ldots,\sigma_n$ are the singular values of $A$. Hence the spectrum of $M$ lies inside
$$
\left[\frac{1-\sqrt{1+4\sigma_1^2}}2,\ \frac{1-\sqrt{1+4\sigma_n^2}}2\right]\cup
\left[\frac{1+\sqrt{1+4\sigma_n^2}}2,\ \frac{1+\sqrt{1+4\sigma_1^2}}2\right].
$$
Since $[\sigma_n,\sigma_1]\subseteq[1,\kappa(A)]$, the above union of intervals is contained in
$$
\mathcal I=\left[\frac{1-\sqrt{1+4\kappa(A)^2}}2,\ \frac{1-\sqrt{5}}2\right]\cup
\left[\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}2,\ \frac{1+\sqrt{1+4\kappa(A)^2}}2\right].
$$