# Quick way to find eigenvalues of anti-diagonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

If $A \in M_n(\mathbb{R})$ is an anti-diagonal $n \times n$ matrix, is there a quick way to find its eigenvalues in a way similar to finding the eigenvalues of a diagonal matrix? The standard way for finding the eigenvalues for any $n \times n$ is usually straightforward, but may sometimes lead to painstaking computational time. Just wondering if there was a quicker way in doing so for any anti-diagonal matrix without having to resort to the standard method of finding the determinant of $A - \lambda I$, where $I$ is the $n \times n$ identity matrix, and setting it equal to $0$ and solving for $\lambda$.

Comment: if $n$ is odd then one eigenvalue will surely be the $\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor$-th term of the matrix

Comment: @Ale: Could you please point me to a reference with regard to your comment of the parity of $n$? I wasn't aware of this fact.

Comment: Yes sure, just consider a antidiagonal matrix of size $n$ with $n=2m+1, \text{for} m\in \Bbb{N}$. Consider the case $n=5$ (you can easily transport it to any odd number, but it is easier for me to explain), then you have a matrix that looks like this

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}0&0&0&0&a_{15}\\0&0&0&a_{24}&0\\0&0&a_{33}&0&0\\0&a_{42}&0&0&0\\a_{51}&0&0&0&0 \end{pmatrix}$$

You can notice that if you multiply $A \cdot  \begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\1\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}$ you get $a_{33}\cdot (0,0,1,0,0)^T$ and so $a_{33}$ is an eigenvalue by definition.

Comment: @Libertron If $n$ is odd then it has a "middle" entry, i.e. the anti-diagonal intersects with the main diagonal.  Consider what happens when you subtract that entry.

Comment: @Ale Technically this would be the $\lceil n/2 \rceil$-th term, no?

Comment: @ErickWong yes sure, i made a mistake

Comment: However i notice now, just by putting some random antidiagonal matrix in wolframalpha, that if $n$ is odd one eigenvalue is $\lceil \frac{n}{2} \rceil$ and the other are all in pairs, that is if $\lambda_1$ is one eigenvalue, then $-\lambda_1$ is also. If $n$ is even then every eigenvalue is in pair. It would be nice to prove this. I'm going to think about it

Answer (score 34, accepted):

For ease of formatting and explanation, I'll be doing everything for the $5 \times 5$ example.  However, the same trick works for any $n \times n$ antisymmetric matrix (though slightly differently for even $n$).

Suppose
$$
A = 
\begin{pmatrix}0&0&0&0&a_{15}\\0&0&0&a_{24}&0\\0&0&a_{33}&0&0\\0&a_{42}&0&0&0\\a‌​_{51}&0&0&0&0 \end{pmatrix}
$$

Here's a neat trick: we note that
$$
A^2 = \pmatrix{
a_{15}a_{51}&&&&\\
&a_{24}a_{42}&&&\\
&&(a_{33})^2&&\\
&&&a_{24}a_{42}&\\
&&&&a_{15}a_{51}\\
}
$$
So, the eigenvalues of $A^2$ are precisely $\{a_{15}a_{51}, a_{24}a_{42}, (a_{33})^2\}$.

Now, note that if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, then $\lambda^2$ must be an eigenvalue of $A^2$.  This gives you six candidates for the eigenvalues of $A$.

---

In fact, with more thorough analysis, we can guarantee that the eigenvalues will be precisely $\lambda = \pm \sqrt{a_{i,(n+1-i)}a_{(n+1-i),i}}$ for $i = 1,\dots,\lfloor n/2\rfloor$ and, for odd $n$, $\lambda = a_{(n+1)/2,(n+1)/2}$.

**Proof that this is the case:** Let $e_1,\dots,e_n$ denote the standard basis vectors.  Let $S_{ij}$ denote the span of the vectors $e_i$ and $e_j$.

Note that $A$ is invariant over $S_{i(n-i)}$ for $i = 1,\dots,\lfloor n/2\rfloor$.  We may then consider the restriction $A_{i(n-i)}: S_{i(n-i)} \to S_{i(n-i)}$, which can be represented by the matrix
$$
\pmatrix{0 & a_{i(n-i)}\\a_{(n-i)i} & 0} 
$$
It suffices to find the eigenvalues of this transformation.

For the case of an odd $n$, it is sufficient to note that $a_{(n+1)/2,(n+1)/2}$ lies on the diagonal with zeros in its row and column.

---

Another explanation: denote the matrix
$S = \pmatrix{e_1 & e_{n} & e_2 & e_{n-1} & \cdots}$

Noting that $S$ is orthogonal (i.e. $S^{-1} = S^{T}$), we find that
$$
SAS^{-1} = 
\pmatrix{
0&a_{1,n}\\
a_{n,1}&0\\
&&0&a_{2,n-1}\\
&&a_{n-1,2}&0\\
&&&&\ddots
}
$$
This matrix is similar, and therefore has the same eigenvalues.  However, it is also block diagonal.

Comment: Do we know if the eigenvalues are positive or negative? I know we can just guess and check the $\pm \lambda$, but can we without guessing?

Comment: @IonSme The second and third sections of my answer require no "guess and check"

Comment: Sorry for my mistake.

Comment: Why are there commas between the terms under the radical in section 2?

Answer (score 8):

Suppose $A$ has even size, say, $2m \times 2m$. Then by reordering the basis we can produce a block diagonal matrix with the same eigenvalues as the original.

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
0      & a_{1,2m} \\
a_{2m,1} & 0   \\
\end{array}
\right)
\oplus
\cdots
\oplus
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
0      & a_{m,m+1} \\
a_{m+1,m} & 0   \\
\end{array}
\right).
$$
The characteristic polynomial is

$$\det(\lambda I - A) = \det\left(\lambda I - \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
0      & a_{1,2m} \\
a_{2m,1} & 0   \\
\end{array}
\right)\right)
\cdots  \det\left(\lambda I - \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
0      & a_{m,m+1} \\
a_{m+1,m} & 0   \\
\end{array}
\right)\right)
= (\lambda^2 - a_{1,2m}a_{2m,1})\cdots(\lambda^2 - a_{m,m+1}a_{m+1,m}) .
$$
and so the eigenvalues are the roots of these factor polynomials, namely both square roots of each of the products $a_{1,2m}a_{2m,1}, \ldots, a_{m,m+1} a_{m+1,m}$.

If $A$ has odd size, say, $(2m + 1) \times (2m + 1)$ when we change basis we can send the middle ($(m+1)$st) element to the end, in which case the characteristic polynomial takes a similar form as in the even case (with indices $> m$ shifted up one), but with an additional factor of $\lambda - a_{m+1, m+1}$, so the additional eigenvalue in this case is just the middle entry of the matrix.

Answer (score 5):

One can actually find the eigenvalues of $A$ **directly** without reordering the indices (note: I'm not saying that this is the quickest or preferred way to find those eigenvalues -- this is not). The eigenvalues of $A$ are just the roots of the characteristic polynomial $\det(xI-A)$. When $n$ is odd, let $m=\frac{n+1}2$ and write
$$
A=\left[\begin{array}{c|c|c}0&0&A_{13}\\ \hline 0&a_{mm}&0\\ \hline A_{31}&0&0\end{array}\right]\tag{$\ast$}
$$
where $A_{13}$ and $A_{31}$ are two anti diagonal matrices of size $m-1$. By Laplace expansion along the middle row, we get $\det(xI-A)=(x-a_{mm})\det\left[\begin{array}{c|c}xI&-A_{13}\\ \hline -A_{31}&xI\end{array}\right]$. Using the [formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/548487) $\det\pmatrix{X&Y\\ Z&W}=\det(XW-YZ)$ when $Z$ and $W$ commute, we further obtain
\begin{align*}
\det(xI-A)&=(x-a_{mm})\det(x^2I-A_{13}A_{31})\\
&= (x-a_{mm})(x^2-a_{1n}a_{n1})(x^2-a_{2,n-1}a_{n-1,2})\cdots\left(x^2-a_{m-1,m+1}a_{m+1,m-1}\right)
\end{align*}
and finding its roots is a trivial matter.

When $n$ is even, the central element in $(\ast)$ vanishes and we may skip the Laplace expansion step. The characteristic polynomial of $A$ is then
$$
(x^2-a_{1n}a_{n1})(x^2-a_{2,n-1}a_{n-1,2})\cdots\left(x^2-a_{\frac n2,\frac n2+1}a_{\frac n2+1,\frac n2}\right).
$$

Comment: Yes, I did think along the line you outlined. My apology for the ignorant edit. Please change it back, adding however a reference to a proof of the determinant formula.

Comment: @Hans Let me thank you for your contributions. It was a useful edit, not an "ignorant" one. It just seemed to suggest that the formula was originally proved or should be proved by using Schur complement, which I think is a bit misleading.

Comment: Thank you for your generous comment. On second thought, this proposition can indeed be proved through analytic continuation by the Schur complement as follows. Suppose $A$ commutes with $C$. $$\det\pmatrix{A+xI&B\\ C&D}=\det(A+xI)\det\left(D-C(A+xI)^{-1}B\right)=\det\big((A+xI)(D-(A+xI)^{-1}CB)\big)=\det\big((A+xI)D-CB\big)$$ 
for all $x$ with large enough $|x|$ to make $A+xI$ nonsingular. But both ends of the above long equation exist and are analytic with respect to all $x$. The equation can be analytically continued to $x=0$. We arrive at the desired determinant equation.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Thanks. Fixed.