# Finding eigenvalues of an anti-diagonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant

Let $A=(a_{ij}) \in M_{n}(\mathbb{R})$ such that
$$a_{ij}=
  \begin{cases} 
      \hfill 1    \hfill & \text{ if $i+j=n+1$} \\
      \hfill 0 \hfill & \text{ otherwise} \\
  \end{cases}      $$

I am required to find determinant and eigenvalues for $n=10$ and $n=100$.

**ATTEMPT**

Eigenvalues for $n=10$ are just set containing elements $1$. So determinant is $1$. But the solution states it should be $-1$. How do I do for $n=100$ and the general case?

Thanks.

Comment: "The eigenvalues for $n=10$ are just set containing element $1$": this sentence makes no sense as written.

Comment: See also [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/921579/quick-way-to-find-eigenvalues-of-anti-diagonal-matrix/921612#921612)

Answer (score 3):

Hint: your matrix is a permutation matrix. The characteristic polynomial of the permutation matrix corresponding to $\sigma\in\mathbf S_n$ is the product of the characteristic polynomials of (the matrices of) the disjoint cycles in the decomposition of $\sigma$, and since the companion matrix for the polynomial $X^d-1$ is the permutation matrix of a $d$-cycle, the characteristic polynomial of such a cycle is $X^d-1$. So all that is left is to find your permutation, its decomposition into disjoint cycles, and to combine the roots of the corresponding factors $X^d-1$ into a big multiset of eigenvalues.

Answer (score 2):

here is way to compute the eigenvalues and eigenvectors. we will look at the cases $n = 2, 4, \cdots$ to see a pattern. i will use the standard basis $e_1, e_2, \cdots, e_n$ where $e_j$ has $1$ at the $j$th  entry and $0$ everywhere else.

let us look at the case $n= 2.$ we have $$Ae_1 = e_2,\, Ae_2 = e_1 \tag 1$$

adding and subtracting the two equations, we get $$A(e_1+e_2) = e_1 + e_2,\ A(e_1 - e_2)=-(e_1-e_2) \tag2 $$ hat is, the eignevalues of $A$ are $\pm 1$ and the corresponding eigenvectors are $e_1\pm e_2.$

now the case $n = 4.$  we have $$Ae_1 = e_4,\, Ae_2 = e_3,\  Ae_3 = e_2,\ Ae_4 = e_1\tag 2$$
 by pairing the first and the fourth, second and the third and using the case for $n = 2,$  we get the eigenvalues and the eigenvectors of $A$ are
$$\pm 1, \ \pm 1, \text{ corresponding eigenvectors are }e_1 \pm e_4 \text{ and } e_2 \pm e_3.$$

i hope you see how to extend this result to $n= 10$ and $n = 100.$

Answer (score 1):

Hint product of eigenvalues is determinant of a particular matrix while sum of trace of a matrix is the sum of eigenvalues. See now we can create a principal diagonal by changing $C_{10} to C_{1}$  and similarly changing till $C_{5} to C_{6}$ so now you get a digonal matrix . Whose $det(A)=1$ but as we have changed $5$ times columns so its $(-1)^5.det(A)=-1.1=-1$ hope you can think for $n=100$

Comment: I think you have to elaborate a little

Comment: Surely! I have edited hope its helpful not the best solution.

Comment: No, In this case, what is the trace ?  How do you find the eigen values ?  These questions come to mind, so once again, please elaborate.

Comment: I have edited it now.

Comment: Certainly determinant and trace do not determine the (multi-)set of eigenvalues completely.

Comment: Of course you are right iys just an hint