# Jordan carnonical form of a clinodiagonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, jordan-normal-form

Let $A$ be a $n\times n$ matrix in the following form
\begin{pmatrix}
&&&a_1\\
&&\cdot&\\
&\cdot&&\\
a_n&&&
\end{pmatrix}
How can we find it Jordan carnonical form? It seems that $n=2$ is easy to calculate. For general $n$, it seems difficult.

Comment: [Related](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/921579/81360)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By an appropriate row/column permutation, your matrix is similar to a block diagonal matrix:
$$ \begin{pmatrix}
0 & a_n \\
a_1 & 0 \\
&& 0 & a_{n-1} \\
&& a_2 & 0 \\
&&&& \ddots \end{pmatrix} $$
From there you can easily Jordanize each block separately.

Answer (score 1):

@Henning Makholm

**A complement, that I give as an answer because it takes some room.**

Let us take the case where $n$ is even and all $a_k >0$ in order not to have to consider special cases (though not especialy difficult).

It is remarkable that this kind of matrices have very simple eigenvalues, **and eigenvectors** as well.

The eigenvalues are immediately computed using the block decomposition of the similar matrix you have given

$$\sqrt{a_1a_{n}}, \ -\sqrt{a_1a_{n}}, \ \sqrt{a_2a_{n-1}}, \ -\sqrt{a_2a_{n-1}} , \cdots .$$

In a surprising way, "the" associated eigenvectors are as well simple:

$$\begin{pmatrix}\sqrt{a_1}\\0\\0\\\cdots\\0\\0\\\sqrt{a_n}\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}\sqrt{a_1}\\0\\0\\\cdots\\0\\0\\-\sqrt{a_n}\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}0\\\sqrt{a_2}\\0\\\cdots\\0\\\sqrt{a_{n-1}}\\0\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}0\\\sqrt{a_2}\\0\\\cdots\\0\\-\sqrt{a_{n-1}}\\0\end{pmatrix}
etc.$$

making a change of base matrix $P$ very simple.