# How to find the Jordan form of an anti-diagonal matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, jordan-normal-form

How to find the Jordan form of an anti-diagonal matrix?

$$\begin{bmatrix} &&&{}a_{1}\\ &&\ddots &\\ &a_{\text{} n-1}&&\\ a_{n}&&& \end{bmatrix}$$

It seems to find the characteristic polynomial and minimal polynomial, but how to find these?

Comment: I imagine the entries that are blank are all $0.$

Comment: Yes, they are all 0.

Comment: Assume everyone is nonzero. It's easy to see the eigenvalues of the square are $a_ia_{n-i+1}$, which tells you the eigenvalues here are among $\pm \sqrt{a_ia_{n-i+1}}$, and then it is equally easy to check "by hand" that all of those are in fact eigenvalues. If those quantities are all distinct then the matrix is diagonalizable and that's the Jordan form. If some are equal then it is harder to say what will happen.

Comment: Think permutation matrices.

Comment: Would have been amazing if I had this help when I was studying for my exam :/ (See 2018P1S2Q9E in https://tartarus.org/gareth/maths/tripos/IB/Linear_Algebra.pdf )

Comment: [See also this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/921579/81360)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The matrix in question is similar via a permutation matrix to
$$
A=\begin{cases}
\pmatrix{0&a_1\\ a_n&0}\oplus\pmatrix{0&a_2\\ a_{n-1}&0}\oplus\pmatrix{0&a_{(n-1)/2}\\ a_{(n+3)/2}&0}\oplus a_{(n+1)/2}&\text{when $n$ is odd},\\
\pmatrix{0&a_1\\ a_n&0}\oplus\pmatrix{0&a_2\\ a_{n-1}&0}\oplus\pmatrix{0&a_{n/2}\\ a_{n/2+1}&0}&\text{when $n$ is even}.\\
\end{cases}
$$
The problem thus reduces to finding the Jordan form of $X=\pmatrix{0&a\\ b&0}$ over the algebraic closure of the underlying field.

- If $X$ has two distinct eigenvalues $r_1$ and $r_2$, its Jordan form is $\pmatrix{r_1&0\\ 0&r_2}$.
- If $X=0$, its Jordan form is obviously itself.
- If $X\ne0$ has a double eigenvalue $r$ (e.g. when $a=0\ne b$ or when the field is $GF(2)$ and $ab=1$), since $X$ is not a scalar matrix, it must be non-diagonalisable. Hence its Jordan form is $\pmatrix{r&1\\ 0&r}$.