# Determinant of block matrix with commuting blocks

Tags: matrices, determinant, block-matrices

I know that given a $2N \times 2N$ block matrix with $N \times N$ blocks like

$$\mathbf{S} = \begin{pmatrix}
A & B\\ 
C & D
\end{pmatrix}$$

we can calculate $$\det(\mathbf{S})=\det(AD-BD^{-1}CD)$$ and so clearly if $D$ and $C$ commute this reduces to $\det(AD-BC)$, which is a very nice property.

My question is, for a general $nN\times nN$ matrix with $N\times N$ blocks where *all of the blocks* commute with each other, can we find the determinant in a similar way? That is, by first finding the determinant treating the blocks like scalars and then taking the determinant of the resulting $N\times N$ matrix.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If $D$ is not invertible then what about this identity $\det(\mathbf{S})=\det(AD-BD^{-1}CD)$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is affirmative. See, e.g., theorem 1 of John Silvester, [*Determinants of Block Matrices*](http://www.ee.iisc.ernet.in/new/people/faculty/prasantg/downloads/blocks.pdf).

Comment: Great! Thanks for the reference