# Proving a determinant of a particular type is always null

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant

Let $n\ge 1$ and $A,B\in\mathrm M_n(\mathbb R)$.

Let's assume that

$$\forall Q\in\mathrm M_n(\mathbb R), \quad \det\begin{pmatrix} I_n & A \\ Q & B\end{pmatrix}=0$$

where $I_n$ is the identity matrix of $\mathrm M_n(\mathbb R)$.

> Can we prove that $\mathrm{rank} \begin{pmatrix}A\\ B\end{pmatrix}<n$?

---

This fact seems quite obvious, but I can't find any straightforward argument to prove it.

*Some ideas.*

With $Q=0$, we deal with a block-triangular matrix, so we have $\det B=0$.

Moreover, with $Q=\lambda I_n$, $\lambda\in\mathbb R$, since it commutes with $B$, we have

$$\forall \lambda\in\mathbb R,\quad \det(B-\lambda A)=0,$$

so if $\det(A)\ne 0$, we have

$$\forall \lambda\in\mathbb R,\quad\det((BA-\lambda I_n)A^{-1})=\det(BA-\lambda I_n)\det(A)^{-1}=0,$$

which means that every $\lambda\in\mathbb R$ is an eigenvalue of $BA$ (since for all $\lambda\in\mathbb R$, $\det(BA-\lambda I_n)=0$), which is absurd.

So $\det(A)=0$ also.

Comment: @E The matrix $\pmatrix{A\\B}$ is not square, so it doesn't make sense to say that its determinant is or isn't zero.

Comment: @BenGrossmann Sorry, I meant that the rank of this matrix is $<n$, I edited.

Comment: Maybe that the rank is less than or equal to $n$?

Comment: @Gregory Yes exactly, I want to prove that the rank is strictly less than $n$.

Comment: @twosigma This is incorrect. For example, with $n = 2$ and 
$$
A = \pmatrix{1&0\\1&0}, \quad B = \pmatrix{0&1\\0&1},
$$
$[A;B]$ has full rank even though neither $A$ nor $B$ have full rank.

Comment: @ancientmathematician Since this is true for all $Q=\lambda I$, that's how I get the "$\forall \lambda$"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is true over any field, not just $\mathbb R$. Note that $\det\pmatrix{I&A\\ Q&B}=\det(B-QA)$. View $A$ and $B$ as two linear maps from a vector space $V$ to another vector space $W$ of the same dimension. View $Q$ as a linear operator on $W$. By changing the bases of $V$ and $W$ separately, we may assume that $A=I_r\oplus0$ where $r=\operatorname{rank}(A)$. Partition $B$ and $Q$ accordingly as $[B_1|B_2]$ and $[Q_1|Q_2]$, where $B_1$ and $Q_1$ each has $r$ columns. Then $B-QA=[B_1-Q_1|B_2]$ is singular for every $Q_1$. Hence $B_2$ has deficient column rank and so does $\pmatrix{A\\ B}=\pmatrix{\ast&0\\ \ast&B_2}$. Since the change of bases amounts to a transformation in the form of $\pmatrix{A\\ B}\mapsto\pmatrix{U&0\\ 0&U}\pmatrix{A\\ B}V$ for some invertible $U$ and $V$, the $\pmatrix{A\\ B}$ before change also has deficient column rank.

Answer (score 3):

Denote
$$M_Q = \begin{pmatrix} I_n & A \\ Q & B\end{pmatrix}, \quad \operatorname{col}(A,B) = \pmatrix{A\\B}.
$$

---

The statement does hold with the additional assumption that $\ker(A) \subseteq \ker B$, i.e. the row-space of $A$ contains that of $B$.

Suppose for contradiction that $\operatorname{col}(A,B)$ has full rank. Let $U$ denote the column space of $A,B$. Let $P$ denote a matrix whose columns form a basis of $U^\perp$. By using column operations on $P$, we can bring $P$ to its column-echelon form, which is
$$
P = \pmatrix{I_n\\ Q}
$$
for some matrix $Q_*$. Because the columns of $P$ form a basis of $U^\perp$ and the columns of $\operatorname{col}(A,B)$ form a basis of $U$, we conclude that the columns of $M_{Q_*}$ form a basis of $\Bbb R^n$, which means that $M_{Q_*}$ is invertible and $\det(M_{Q_*}) \neq 0$.

Thus, $\operatorname{col}(A,B)$ indeed fails to have full rank if $\det(M_Q) = 0$ for all $Q$.

Comment: For the counterexample I am getting $\det M_Q = \det (IB - QA) = -q_{21}$ rather than $\det (IB - AQ)$. Why doesn't your proof apply without restriction?

Comment: @Coriolanus Because without the restriction, we can't guarantee the column-echelon form of $P$

Comment: @Coriolanus that's strange about the determinant; not sure what I would have done wrong there

Comment: If you read the rules here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/548476/formula-for-determinant-of-block-matrix-with-commuting-blocks/548487#548487 I don't think we can get $\det (IB - AQ)$ from the top matrices commuting?

Comment: @Coriolanus you're right, we have $\det(BI - QA)$ from the second line in the top answer