# Eigenvalue problem!!

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-analysis

I just want to know is there any short trick to get all the eigenvalues of the below matrix ? I am expecting some easy way due to its blocks structure, which I don't know much about.

$A=\begin{bmatrix} 
a & b&e&0\\
c& d&0&e\\
f & 0&0&0\\
0& g&0&0
\end{bmatrix}$

Thanks in advance. Any help/hint will be appreciated.

Comment: To calculate the eigenvalue, you have to calculate the determinant. Now use the Laplace method to find the determinat.

Comment: @GiovanniFebbraro The determinant does not give much information on the eigenvalues (it only gives what the product of all eigenvalues is).

Comment: Of course, I meant the determinat of $A-\lambda I $

Comment: @GiovanniFebbraro The OP cannot guess what you mean...

Answer (score 4):

I don't think there are any tricks, but the calculation can be made slightly shorter by using block matrices. Let $X=\pmatrix{a&b\\ c&d}$ and $Y=\pmatrix{f&0\\ 0&g}$. Then $\lambda I-A=\pmatrix{\lambda I-X&-eI\\ -Y&\lambda I}$. Since the two sub-blocks on the bottom row commute, we have
\begin{aligned}
\det(\lambda I-A)
&=\det\left((\lambda I-X)(\lambda I)-(-eI)(-Y)\right)\\
&=\det(\lambda^2 I-\lambda X-eY)\\
&=(\lambda^2-\lambda a-ef)(\lambda^2-\lambda d-eg)-(-\lambda b)(-\lambda c).
\end{aligned}
This is a quartic polynomial in $\lambda$. There is, in theory, an [explicit radical formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function) for its zeroes.

Comment: Can you provide a reference to why it is important that the bottom two subblocks commute?

Comment: @MateenUlhaq https://math.stackexchange.com/a/548487