# Calculating the determinant of a $2n \times 2n$ matrix by means of a decomposition into four $n \times n$ blocks

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, block-matrices

I want to calculate the determinant of this matrix:

$\left( \begin{array}{cccccccc}
0 & * & * & * & * & 0 & * & 0 
\\
 * & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & *
\\
*& 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & * & *
\\
 * & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & * & *
\\
* & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & * & *
\\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & * & * 
\\
 * & 0 & * & * & * & * & 0 &* 
\\
 0 & * & * & * & * & * & * & 0 
\end{array}\right)$

using the methode that says that:   $ det \left( \begin{array}{cc} A & B\\ C & D \end{array}\right) =det (AD-BC)$ under some conditions, but I do not achieve it.
Can some one help?

Comment: I have taken the liberty to change your title which in particular hadn't the term "determinant".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us name $M$ your matrix.

I am going to show that $\det(M)=0$.

You know that changing the order or rows and columns (said in matricial terms : pre- or post multiplying $M$ by permutation matrices) preserves the determinant up to a sign change. We can do such rows and columns permutations in such a way that the $5 \times 5$ block of zeros visible inside the matrix is moved in the lower-left corner.

We are now with the following matrix :

$$M'=\left( \begin{array}{c|c}A&B\\  \hline 0&D\end{array}\right)=$$
$$
=\left( \begin{array}{cccc|cccc}
*& * & * & * & * & * & * & *
\\
*& * & * & * & * & * & * & * 
\\
*& * & * & * & * & * & * & *
\\0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & * & * & *\\
\hline
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & * & * & *\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & * & * & *\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & * & * & *\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & * & * & *
\end{array}\right)$$

with a $2 \times 2$ partition into blocks themselves $4 \times 4$. Due to the fact that the $C$ block is a block of zeros, we can conclude that :

$$\det(M')=\det(A)\det(D) \tag{1}$$

(see Remark below).

But $A$ has a row of zeros ; therefore $\det(A)=0$, and, as a consequence, $\det(M')=0$,... and $\det(M)=0$.

Remark : (1) is a known result, but one can deduce it from "your" rule,

$$\det(M')=\det(AD-BC)$$

being  *essential* to twin this rule with the condition : **iff $C$ and $D$ commute** (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/548487/305862)) which is the case here because $C=0$. Then $$\det(AD-BC)=\det(AD)=\det(A)\det(D).$$

Comment: Any comment ?...

Comment: It is clear thanks

Comment: If you don't think there is a better answer to come, please think to validate it.

Comment: I did thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you want to calculate determinant of matrix over than 2x2, you can use a basic technique *expansion by row*. For example, a matrix is

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{}
1 & 2 & 3\\
4 & 5 & 6\\
7 & 8 & 9\\
\end{array} \right)
$$

You can divide it to three 2x2 matrices:

$$
1\det\left(
\begin{array}{}
5 & 6\\
8 & 9\\
\end{array} \right) -
2\det\left(
\begin{array}{}
4 & 6\\
7 & 9\\
\end{array} \right) +
3\det\left(
\begin{array}{}
4 & 5\\
7 & 8\\
\end{array} \right)
$$

Now you can calculate them one by one, and add them together.

If matrix is 4x4, you can divide it to 4 3x3 matrices and divide them to 12 2x2 matrices.

Comment: If you don't understand my example, I think visual example maybe can help you [Determinant of a Matrix](https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/matrix-determinant.html)

Comment: On this site, there are elementary techniques that are too basic to be recalled. "Laplace expansion" of a determinant along a row or a column is one of those. Besides such an approach is ill-adapted for a $8 \times 8$ matrix, leading to too heavy calculations.

Comment: @JeanMarie Thanks you to expand my knowledge! I also think it has too heavy calculations, but I don't know other methods.